# How could a pandemic trigger a renaissance?

Tags: society, technology, post-apocalypse, diseases, post-scarcity

In all this gloomy pandemic reporting of the last 3/4 years nobody ever noticed that [one of the worst pandemics in known history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death) happened at the beginning of the renaissance and it did not stop it. It even brought on the long term benefits for the base [economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequences_of_the_Black_Death#Effect_on_the_peasantry).

> The great population loss brought favorable results to the surviving peasants in England and Western Europe. There was increased social mobility, as depopulation further eroded the peasants' already weakened obligations to remain on their traditional holdings.

[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequences_of_the_Black_Death#Effect_on_urban_workers)

> In the wake of the drastic population decline brought on by the plague, wages shot up and labourers could move to new localities in response to wage offers

At this point I thought that the pandemic itself could be the trigger for a new renaissance. But how?

I'll assume a pandemic at the level of the black death, killing between 30% and 50% of the population. What factors could trigger a renaissance afterwards? I'll try and outline some of them, an eventual answer might tell me if they are correct or not.

At the beginning I thought that halving the population could bring a period of abundance for the survivors, but then I remembered that everything depends on energy, including food production and availability of clean water. Nowadays we are not able to meet the energy demand of most of the population, so halving it would not solve the problem of scarcity. There must be something else.

The most obvious factor would be the decline of the authority, it would be more difficult to impose all the small bureaucratic rules designed to protect the incumbents in each economic sector (told from a European point of view). It would be also more difficult to enforce the American patents designed to restrict some sectors of the market to big tech. A new competitive economy would emerge where small businesses might have a more prominent role.

Another factor could be a weakening of the current financial structure which might also weaken the grip on the media and allow new ideas to emerge (Yes I am aware that on paper there is freedom of expression in the Western world). The difficulty faced by the authority to curtail new ideas in the period between 1300 and 1500 was a major factor of the renaissance.

Another factor could be the failure of the speculative economy. A big chunk of today's financial sector is just a self supporting endless circle of money. With a drastic reduction of the workforce an entire sector that skims on the real economy would not be sustainable, finance would have to concentrate on supporting the real economy turning around the current situation. On the same line the legal sector would have to be simplified, reducing the cost, but also the length and the number of the legal actions, the number of lawyers would be reduced taking a weight off the economy.

Which of these factors is more likely to contribute?

Please. Disasters thinkers framed in the Hollywood mindset ignore this question.

Comment: I presume we are talking about a black-death level pandemic in the modern era.

Comment: My first thought would horrify Disney. Holding on to it until this evening ;)

Comment: Questions asking for idea generation, or brainstorming are not a good fit for this site. Instead of asking us to make up your world for you, can you try to build it yourself and come to us to solve any specific issues you encounter.

Comment: What do you mean by *"a new renaissance"*? A proliferation of Bourne-Again self-proclaimed Christians? The return of the good standards of a classical education? Wheelock's Latin becoming a world-wide bestseller? The beautiful classicist paintings promoted by the Art Renewal Center eliminating modernist doodles from galleries? (And after the economic devastation induced by losing 50% of the workforce, *of course* there will be a rebound as humanity gears up to restore standards of living. It may take some time, but it will happen.)

Comment: "One idea is that the removal of the incumbents could remove a lot of obstacles to small competitors in all the economic sectors."  In the current economic milieu, what would kill the incumbents would be demand destruction/supply chain disruption, not the deaths of its owners/employees.  Businesses are not tied to the fleshy bodies of their components.

Comment: One aspect to consider: the renaissance does not happen in the generation that experienced the pandemic but one, two, or three generations later. The survivors are traumatized but welcoming all solutions. It is that attitude of welcoming new solutions that gets passed down to their children and grandchildren which allows a renaissance to flourish. (A counter example is the lack of renaissance that did not happen in the South after the Civil War. They did not welcome new solutions but looked back at the "good days.") A renaissance is not mandatory after a pandemic.

Comment: The Black Death was spread all over by Genoese traders (associated with Venice, the 'Amazon' of their day).  The Venetians also sent Marco Polo to give them exclusive status trading with the Mongols, who then followed the trade routes to subjugate Kievan Rus and give plague to the Genoese.  The Venetians also destroyed Byzantium as their way of fighting the Fourth Crusade.  Together, these meant that a vast fortune in looted art, followed by refugee scholars as the East Roman Empire collapsed, caused a "Renaissance" in the West Roman Empire ... and the Black Death was its sister.

Comment: Interesting question. I can think of a scenario, but there are too many thinkable scenarios. Examples and asking "what else" won't help, it remains an open question. We can't invent your story for you.. vtkc

Answer (score 8):

I've read/seen that one of the biggest follow-on effects of the Great Plague of the 14th century killing between 1/3 and 1/2 of the population of Europe was that everyone who survived was suddenly (comparatively) rich.  Land was consolidated, agricultural equipment was left unclaimed (and then claimed, of course), the same amount of land that could barely feed everyone now provided an ample reserve, so even the very poorest were better off due to food prices dropping.

It was this sudden relative wealth that (it's claimed) had the biggest impact on society moving from "just getting by" to "moving forward."

Comment: And wages increased dramatically, as there was a lot of work to do and few people to do it. Work for wages became widespread, killing the old feudal mode of production.

Comment: Yes. The people *doing* the work found themselves in a much strengthened position. If Lord Ass next door was no better than Lord Douchebag whose lands you were living on, then there wasn't much reason for uprooting. If, however, the aftermath of the Black Death meant Lord Ass's surviving son, Lord Notsobad was willing to ease up on the burden of working his land because he desperately needed the work done and was willing to offer more, suddenly staying on Lord Douchebag's land was a lot less appealing.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism for this isn't mysterious. Under normal circumstances, those with resources strive to control society and information. This pulls resources out of support networks until they're barely capable of supporting themselves, much less the communities that rely upon them. Our society mirrors that, attempting to "eliminate fat" wherever it is found.

Nobody (with money) considers this a problem until the system is under strain.

War isn't this kind of strain because we now have "sustainable war," where it all happens elsewhere and everything is kept within a budget, bloated as it is. There are no uncontrolled issues.

Ecological disasters aren't this kind of strain because they are virtually instantaneous, and dealt with by taxing the future.

Pandemics are a persistent strain that can't be ignored or budgeted for. They attract denial because they're the kind of expense that businesses want to insist be treated as "externalities," a.k.a., not their problem. The workers can't afford to soak the cost of this because it's literally life-threatening, and the wealthy have eroded their support networks. The disconnect between the wealthy and the workers forces a re-thinking of the balance, and forces a recognition of how denial is a dangerous, even deadly, factor in social cohesion.

In the modern world, we have a social network that pushes Identity Politics, encouraging people to accept what their leaders say out of fear of loss of social standing. This creates creeping cognitive dissonance that is tolerable among the entrenched, but is obvious self-confirmation bias from the outside.

The situation creates an erosion of institutions, and encourages flexibility. This could be a ripe circumstance for an enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

In the wake of a planet wide disaster, the goal of society shifts from profit to altruism. The governments and people of the world have a common goal -- helping each other. Everyone is a victim. Everyone is a hero.

The nations stop warring with each other. The planet becomes one big 100 year long humanitarian crusade.

When we finally overcome the plague, our population has been reduced by nine tenths. There are few enough people that environmental issues are not a problem any more. We have already shared resources equally among everyone. The economy has collapsed and been rebuilt around this fact. We have a post-scarcity society.

Comment: IF such a disaster ever comes to pass, I hope you are right and I am wrong.  Everyone would have a common goal. Survival, and the continuation if their own DNA line. back to basics. If by chance altruism demonstrates in the myriad of situation in this even as beneficial, and quickly beneficial. people will stampede like wild animals.

Comment: "The nations stop warring with each other."  Except they didn't.  The 14th century was the beginning of a couple of the longest running wars in history, was it not?  The Hundred Years War began just a few year after the worst pass of the Great Plague through Europe.

Comment: @ZeissIkon What must we change about the disaster to get the outcome I predict?

Comment: @Gillgamesh Maybe they both happen, one after the other.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I don't think that the happened because of the plague, but more in spite of it.   IMHO the renaissance, and indeed the wars surrounding those centuries can be laid at the feet of cinnamon, ginger, silk, pepper etc. The spice trade brought staggering wealth, trade communication of ideas, culture and  knowledge into the mix of society.  I mean just wealth, adjusted $. Dutch East India Co. = ~7 TRILLION $. Apple only exceeded 1 trillion in 2018. Thats alot of people and good moving back and forth.

Comment: @Daron, Indeed there will be ups and downs. But a renaissance is something different. And will the culture that survives be able to learn and implement effective change after a resurgence? Maybe, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see this as being a possibility. Certainly in smaller more egalitarian communities after a time you might conceivably see a boom in overall growth. But as a whole the systems society is built on today are far too specialized and concentrated. The impact of a 50% population would be destabilizing and devastating. Just like in nature the  environment changes, the largest and most specialized are the hardest hit the first to go extinct. I fear such a if such scenario comes to pass, when these large systems begin to fail they will not go out quietly and will take out much of the surrounding infrastructure (of all types) with it, that the smaller more adaptable populations could use to grow, will only be able to survive rather than progress.

During the renaissance it was a very different story. you only had to get your hands on a  good plow and a someone that could read,  and you were back to the norm of the society at that point. Now how much would you need to rebuild to get yourself to anything close to 21st century standards of living?

Though personally some days that plow and a good book doesn't look so much like a down grade...

Comment: If it really were this way, why the Spanish flu did not cause a collapse in the countries already weakened by the war? Do you have a scientifically reasonable explanation?

Comment: "systems society is built on today are far too specialized and concentrated" Did you have a look at how many student every single highly specialised university course has?

Comment: 1917/18, I'd posit even up until the 1970's though industrialized we were still very aguarian. Even in urban settings in 1917 it was common to see gardens. small mom and pos for everything under the sun.  if you couldn't get it from here you could from there OR make due with something you produce. Not super specialized as we are today and are likely to continue to be. Imagine instantly removing walmart from the socal map today,  leaving a vacuum.  Competed utter total chaos. After the resources from the smaller distributors have been used up. "Every society is only three meals away from chaos"

Comment: "Every society is only three meals away from chaos"  If I remember correctly the quote you reduced the number of meals. So to an unsubstiantiated  claim you added your own.

Comment: No pretty sure Lenin said 3. Irrelevant though the number is...

Comment: "Lenin said 3" And his follower Stalin used starvation to stifle resistance and impose the Bolshevik order. They really proved with their actions  the validity of such claims.

Comment: Glad we agree :)

Comment: "Glad we agree :) " I see you are very good at spinning and trolling. Unfortunately when it comes to providing scientific evidence you are lacking.

Comment: What scientific evidence can you provide for a wholly hypothetical question? You asked a question, I gave my opinion, stated why I was of that opinion with reasonionable answers. At Least AS scientific as was your question...
YOU asked me again for more reasoning, I provided, you zeroed in saying I misquoted (the part of the quote was irrelevant  to the topic but....) I didn't Misquote. I attempt to disengage by agreeing with your last post. Now... I... am the troll. Why do I just get the feeling you just don't like being disagreed with.